# How to include custom JS file in a WP custom page

Tags: javascript, custom-wordpress-pages

I have made a custom page like form.php in wp theme folder & also have a custom java script file in theme's default 'js' folder. how can i include this js file in that page?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can just put JS file using `script tag` e.g.

```
?> <script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script> <?php
```

Ping me if you have any query

Update:

You can add JS scripts conditionally on any page

```
// load_js_assets function could be any where to load file
function load_js_assets() {
// is_page is a WP conditional and will load if page id will match
    if( is_page( ID ) ) {
// your conditional block to load scripts
        wp_enqueue_script('my-js', 'PATH TO JS FILE', array('jquery'), '', false);
    } 
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js_assets');
```

You may take a look of other WP conditionals according to your use case here. https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Comment: adding get_header(); the JS file is running all page. i need both js file and header function. but i want to run js file in one page

Comment: I have updated ans. leme know if you need further clarification

Comment: where to add it?? in function.php?? for custom page which function should use is_page or is_page_template??

Comment: On which condition you wanna add js file? You can add it in header. Current code will check for matching page id and will load the code.

Comment: You problem is addressed or you still have confusion ?

Comment: not solved trying to enqueuing but not working..tnx for ur help

Comment: Welcome.
You may add ans. to your question so community also get benefit of it.